# Compute $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{x+\sqrt{1+x}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Compute $\int \limits_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{x+\sqrt{1+x}}$.
I tried to subtitute $t=\sqrt{1+x}$ and this led me to having to compute $\int \limits_{1}^{\sqrt 2}\frac{2t dt}{t^2+t-1}$. I tried PFD here, but the computations are really messy and I am stuck. Any suggestions?

Comment: There isn't going to be a clean answer, because the answer is will be a mess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split the integral in two:
$$\int \limits_{1}^{\sqrt 2}\frac{2t\,\mathrm  dt}{t^2+t-1}=\int \limits_{1}^{\sqrt 2}\frac{(2t+1)\,\mathrm dt}{t^2+t-1}-\int \limits_{1}^{\sqrt 2}\frac{\mathrm dt}{t^2+t-1}$$
and write the latter integral in canonical form:
$$\int \limits_{1}^{\sqrt 2}\frac{\mathrm dt}{\bigl(t+\frac12\bigr)^2-\frac54}$$

Comment: Numerator of first integral looks like should be $2t+1$ .

Comment: Oh! yes. Fixed. Thank you for pointing it!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: It is $$\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{x+1}}=\frac{x-\sqrt{x+1}}{x^2-1-x}$$

Comment: The denominator is missing a square somewhere, yes?

Comment: Yes, just corrected!

Answer (score 0):

With $$t=2\sqrt{1+x}+1,$$

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{x+\sqrt{1+x}}=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\dfrac{t-1}2\,dt}{\dfrac{\left(t-1\right)^2}4-1+\dfrac{t-1}2}=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{2t-2}{t^2-5}\,dt
\\=\log|t^2-5|-\frac1{\sqrt5}\left(\log|t-\sqrt5|-\log|t+\sqrt5|\right).$$